# eclipse RAP: Why are my dynamic Handled Menu Items able to call @CanExecute but not @Execute

Tags: command, handler, rcp, e4, eclipse-rap

I am creating a dynamic submenu for a popup menu in a RAP e4 application. The menu contains one or several handled menu items all using the same command but different command parameters. I have also written a handler for this command that so far is supposed to do nothing but log the parameter values.

Here's the code creating the submenu:

```
@AboutToShow
public void aboutToShow(List<MMenuElement> items, MPart part, MApplication app) {
    AnnotationEditorPart aEPart = (AnnotationEditorPart) part.getObject();
    List<IAnnotationElement> elements = aEPart.getGrid().getElementsOfCurrentlySelectedCategory();
    String catName = "";
    if (aEPart.getGrid().getCurrentlySelectedCategory() != null) {
        catName = aEPart.getGrid().getCurrentlySelectedCategory().getName();
    }

    MMenu subMenu = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createMenu();
    subMenu.setLabel("Add Element...");
    items.add(subMenu);

    if (catName.equals("")) {
        //Not a category
        return;
    }

    for (IAnnotationElement element: elements) {
        if (element.isToBeDisplayed()) {
            continue;
        }

        MHandledMenuItem dynamicItem = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createHandledMenuItem();
        dynamicItem.setLabel(element.getName());
        dynamicItem.setContributorURI("platform:/plugin/org.bgbm.annosys.ui");

        MCommand command = app.getCommand(COMMAND_ID);

        dynamicItem.setCommand(command);

        MParameter parameter = MCommandsFactory.INSTANCE.createParameter();
        parameter.setName("org.bgbm.annosys.ui.commandparameter.annotationElementToAddToCategory");
        parameter.setValue(element.getName());
        dynamicItem.getParameters().add(parameter);

        MParameter parameter2 = MCommandsFactory.INSTANCE.createParameter();
        parameter2.setName("org.bgbm.annosys.ui.commandparameter.annotationCategoryToAddElementTo");
        parameter2.setValue(catName);
        dynamicItem.getParameters().add(parameter2);

        subMenu.getChildren().add(dynamicItem);

        dynamicItem.setEnabled(true);
        dynamicItem.setCommand(command);
    }
}
```

Essentially, I get a list of elements and create a menut item for each element to add that element to the chosen category. All I need for this is the name of the category and the name of the element, so I put those into the command parameters.

This sort of works. here's the handler:

```
package org.bgbm.annosys.ui.application.parts.handlers;

import javax.inject.Named;

import org.bgbm.annosys.logging.Logger;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.CanExecute;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;

public class AddAnnotationElementToCategoryCommandHandler {

    /** Default {@link Logger} instance of this class */
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger();

    @Execute
    public void execute(@Named("org.bgbm.annosys.ui.commandparameter.annotationElementToAddToCategory") String elementName,
            @Named("org.bgbm.annosys.ui.commandparameter.annotationCategoryToAddElementTo") String categoryName) {
        logger.debug("#### clicked: " + elementName + ", " + categoryName);
    }

    @CanExecute
    public boolean canExecute(@Named("org.bgbm.annosys.ui.commandparameter.annotationElementToAddToCategory") String elementName,
            @Named("org.bgbm.annosys.ui.commandparameter.annotationCategoryToAddElementTo") String categoryName) {
        logger.debug(elementName + ", " + categoryName);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The interesting thing is that canExecute clearly triggers. I get the expected result in the console and depending on whether I return true or false, the items are enabled or disabled as usual.

However, clicking the item results in absolutely no reaction. There is nothing in the log and any other code I put into the execute function is likewise ignored. The method is simply never called, it seems.

What could be the reason for this?

EDIT:
I have now tried several different ways of tying commands to dynamic menu items, but the results remain the same.
I'd like to to debug this with a breakpoint at the moment of menu item selection, but I don't know where that breakpoint should go, since the framework handles the entire menu function and the execute method is never called.

Maybe someone can help me with that, at least?

Answer (score 0):

As far as debugging goes, you could set conditional breakpoints in the various `invoke(...)` methods of `org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory` (the condition being something like `qualifier == org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute.class`).

If you want to go even further into the framework internals, you could check where `org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute` is referenced and follow that reference trail, which will probably lead you to a menu item renderer.